# Flutter não conecta na API quando executado com F5

Tags: flutter, debug

Estou desenvolvendo um app em Flutter no VSCode (Flutter 3.13.2) e (Dart 3.1.0), meu backend é uma API em .net core. De uns meses pra cá quando executo o app com F5 (Start Debugging), o app executa normalmente, porém no momento de conectar-se a API, simplesmente não tenho resposta alguma, não retorna nenhum código de erro e app fica travado. Utilizo Dio para as requisições. Antes de conectar na API eu conecto normalmente ao Firebase. Na execução se eu teclo F5 para forçar a continuidade da execução é retornado o seguinte erro:

DioException [unknown]: null
Error: HandshakeException: Connection terminated during handshake

Em execuções em necessidade breakpoint funciona normalmente, faço deploy normalmente. Porém necessito depurar o código e não estou conseguindo.

Algumas das minhas tentaticas para resolver foi atualizando o ambiente e revisando o launch.json, mas sem sucesso.
Launch.json:

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [

    {
        "name": "Nome_APP",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "dart",

    },
    {
        "name": "Nome_APP (profile mode)",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "dart",
        "flutterMode": "profile"
    },
    {
        "name": "Nome_APP (release mode)",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "dart",
        "flutterMode": "release"
    },
    {
        "name": "Nome_APP (debug mode)",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "dart",
        "program": "lib/main.dart",
        "flutterMode": "debug",
    },
]
```

}

Answer (score -2):

É provável que seu backend tenha um `self-signed certificate`, logo ele não é válido, pra evitar que o handshake na conexão seja terminado por conta disso, só dar bypass nisso ao iniciar o app.

```
void main() {
  HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback =
          (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
  }
}
```